# Check if the range time is 30 minutes before and after a new day

Tags: php, codeigniter, datetime, range

I have date and time stored separately in different column in a table. So I'm trying to check if the current time is 30 minutes early or late from the time in the database.

Let's say I have a list of date and time stored like this:

**date**         |       **time** 
2020-05-29             00:10:00 
2020-05-29             09:00:00

If my current date is `2020-05-28` and time is `23:50:00`, the nearest date & time should be the 1st row `2020-05-29, 00:10:00` where the range should be from `2020-05-28, 23:35:00 - 2020-05-29, 00:35:00`

I have the code done but it can only detect the range of time on the same date.

```
$currentTime = time();
$minTime     = date("H:i", strtotime('-30 minutes', $currentTime));
$maxTime     = date("H:i", strtotime('+30 minutes', $currentTime));

// My query to get the list of date and time on one specific date and populate to $datetimeArr
// $sql = 'SELECT id, date, time FROM table WHERE date = "'.date('Y-m-d').'"';

$datetimeArr = [
    [
        'date' => '2020-05-29',
        'time' => '00:10:00'
    ],
    [
        'date' => '2020-05-29',
        'time' => '09:00:00'
    ],
];

foreach ($datetimeArr as $k => $row) {
    if($row['time'] >= $minTime && $row['time'] <= $maxTime) {
        $nearestDate = $row;
        continue;
    }
}
```

So the issue is, I'm unable to get the range correctly if it is 30 minutes before of after a new day.

Comment: Don't use strings, use `strtotime` integer values. Maybe something like `strtotime($row['date'] . ' ' . $row['time']) >= time() - 1800 || strtotime($row['date'] . ' ' . $row['time']) <= time() + 1800` change operations as needed.. also might want to store `time` outside of operation so it's not calculating during execution.

Comment: @user3783243 Will try it out, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you do this with the mysql query that takes the data? It would be way simpler than doing it with php foreaches.

```
SELECT * FROM `TABLE` WHERE `time` > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 MINUTE) AND `time` < DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 MINUTE)
```

Update with a quirky solution for your case:

```
SELECT * from TableName where CONCAT(date, ' ', time) between DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 MINUTE) and DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 MINUTE)
```

That would concatenate the date and time fields into a single datetime.

Comment: @user3783243 absolutely. It is much simpler code and working more efficient.

Comment: @MitkoDelibaltov what about the date? If it is 30 min before or after the new day? Because for some reason I cannot merge the date and time together.

Comment: @MitkoDelibaltov Ah I see. It's actually doing the job. Thank you!

Comment: Hi, Leon

It's a heck of a weird solution but that should work for you. That contatenates the date and time as if they were together and then does the check.
SELECT * from `TableName` where CONCAT(`date`, ' ', `time`) between DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 MINUTE) and DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 MINUTE)